# How can I get a tensor from a capture()

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I want to know how can I get the tensor from a capture I have the following code:

```
const wcImg = await webcam.capture();
face = tf.tensor(wcImg.print(), [1, 112, 112, 3], 'int32')
model.predict(face);
```

But in this case I couldn't execute predict because,

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: values passed to tensor(values) must be a
> number/boolean/string or an array of numbers/booleans/strings, or a
> TypedArray

I tried without `print()` too, but I got the same response.

How can I get the tensor from the `wcImg`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can use this:

```
const wcImg = await webcam.capture();
const tensor = await wcImg.data();
```